# next-auth: Why occurs 'OAuthCallback' error only in production?

Tags: next.js, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run, next-auth

I want add signin features using 'GoogleProvider' in next-auth.

I finished google cloud and firebase settings

> - OAuth 2.0 client ID in Credentials
> - App domain, Authorized domains in OAuth consent screen
> - create web app in firebase project settings

and [...nextauth].ts code is below:

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import KakaoProvider from "next-auth/providers/kakao"
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { db } from "../../../firebase.config";

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_DEV as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_DEV as string
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60
    },
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(db.app.options),
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login'
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user, token }) {
            return session;
        }
    },
    debug: true
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This project is deploying with Github Actions, Cloud Run, Firebase Hosting.

It works very well in local but not works in production.
Interestingly, It works well in Cloud Run project service URL.

Only not works in domain web page that used Firebase Hosting.

so, I tried these

> - change Authorized redirect URIs in OAuth 2.0 client ID
> - Edit app registration in OAuth consent screen
> - `callbackUrl` property in signIn function

Is this problem caused by Firebase Hosting?
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

---

+add

When I was looking log in Cloud Run, I found these logs:

> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error checks.state argument is missing.
>
> error: TypeError: checks.state argument is missing.
> name: 'OAuthCallbackError'

Comment: Follow the error message, your are missing to specify the "state" param and that leads to inconsistent redirects. Cross check the configuration of your auth client code. Look in the docs for the params it wants and make sure to have all the required once.

Comment: Hi @FabioB. Sorry for the late check your comment. I changed my deploy environment Google Cloud Run to AWS. And add **allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true** in Provider. And then, error is disappeared